# TSQL pattern or reg expression to ensure all rows returned for varchar column are strictly alphanumeric

Tags: regex, t-sql, char, varchar, alphanumeric

I have researched this, but the most obvious answer on stackoverflow is for a converse question, and I can't quite get it to match my situation.

I need a TSQL  reg expression to ensure all rows returned for a particular varchar column(denoted col1 here) are strictly alphanumeric  (that is, any row with even one non-alphanumeric char is excluded)

Something like

```
where col1 like 'regExpGoesHere'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the value does *not* match a string containing something that is *not* a letter or number:

```
WHERE F NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9]%'
```

<sup>(These are patterns, not Regular Expressions)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can try the opposite

```
WHERE col1 NOT LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add Regular Expression parsing to SQL server, using a CLR function.  See here for a great example click here http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/08/adding-regular-expressions-regex-to-sql.html

Comment: This is nice, but IMHO, somewhat complicated!